# Bison recognizing different tokens before and after reduce

Tags: bison

RELOP can be : `== | != | < | > | <= | >=`

& I have this rule in bison which should be recognized:

```
 →
```

This is part of the code in LEX folder:

```
=           {return ASSIGN;}
[<=|>=]                         {return RELOP1;}
[<|>]                           {return RELOP3;}
```

This is a code in my ypp folder:

```
%right    ASSIGN
%left     RELOP2
%left     BINOP2
%nonassoc RELOP1
%nonassoc RELOP3

Exp: Exp RELOP1 Exp { output::printProductionRule(46);}
        | Exp RELOP3 Exp { output::printProductionRule(46);}
        | Exp RELOP2 Exp { output::printProductionRule(46);}
```

This is the test:

```
int bar() {
    if (bar <= bar >= bar) {
        print("Then you got your associativity wrong");
    }
}
```

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot attached, bison recognizes the first '<=' (RELOP1) in the IF before doing the reduce but the second time it recognizes only the assign! What would cause that? bison

Thank you:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[<=|>=]` is a *character class*, which matches just a single character, in this case if that character is one of `<`, `=`, `|`, or `>`. (Putting the same character twice — `=`, in this case — inside a character class is permitted, but had no effect.)

You wanted `"<="|">="`.

If two patterns match the same longest string, flex always returns the first one in the scanner definition. So the first token produced by flex was `<`, which matched `RELOP1` because `RELOP3` comes later in the file; then it matched `=` as `ASSIGN` because that comes earlier.

I'm sure Flex produced the warning that the `RELOP3` rule cannot match anything. This warning should never be ignored; it almost always indicates an error in your patterns.

Note also that the `RELOP3` rule also matches `|`, which is probably not what you want.

Please read the documentation on [(f)lex patterns](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/Patterns.html#Patterns).